# how to show the SettingsActivity when pressing on 'Settings' button ?

Tags: android

I define a SettingsActivity on my app and i want to show this activity when pressing on the 3 dot on the right side of the screen.

[image]

How to do it ? 
I can't find any manual/demo that help me to do it.

Comment: That doesn't display an activity. It displays the overflow menu, if one is needed by your activity or fragment. So, add a "Settings" menu item, with `showAsAction="never"`, and it will appear in the overflow menu. You can then display your `SettingsActivity` when the user taps that menu item.

Comment: @CommonsWarebut    how to pop it up ? ?  ?

Comment: Call `startActivity()`, the same way as you would to start any other activity. Do that in `onOptionsItemSelected()` if the user taps your "Settings" menu item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, create a menu resource file and add the following code.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
   <item 
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Settings"/>
 </group>
```

then, in your MainActivity (Activity where you want to show the three dots in toolbar) create a method onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionItemSelected,

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater.inflate(R.id.menu_settings, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.settings);
    return true;
  }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
     int id = item.getId();
     if (id == R.id.settings){
          startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
     }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```